# How to access the file in servlet which is upload in jsp using input type=file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

If any one has an idea

how can i access a file in servlet that are upload in jsp for example

my jsp file is

upload.jsp

```
<body action="Check" method="get">
<form name="f1">
<input type="file">
<input type="submit" value="Click Me">
</form>
</body>
```

Check.java

Now i need that file in my Check.java file so how can i access that file in my servlet file (Check.java)

Please any one has an idea please suggess me.

Comment: look at my update answer.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a parameter with the form name getParameter("f1")

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm)  to process uploaded file in Servlet.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm

Answer (score 0):

Check this uploaded file in Servlet as:

```
<form method="post" action="check" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table>
                     <tr>
                        <td> Photo: </td>
                        <td><input type="file" name="photo" size="50"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input type="submit" value="Save">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

---

***update:***

```
    // Get part using HttpServletRequest’s getPart() method

    Part filePart = request.getPart("photo");

    // Extract image name from content-disposition header of part

   String imageName = getFileName(filePart);

    System.out.println("***** imageName: " + imageName);
```

[click:1](http://www.javatutorials.co.in/servlet-3-0-image-upload-example/)

[click:2](http://javasantoshanand.blogspot.in/2013/05/how-to-upload-image-using-jspservlet.html)

Comment: But,
how can i access that file in servlet
when i use
request.getParameter("photo");
but,it gave me fake path

Comment: but there is no any method like getFileName

Comment: you should goto refer that link